# Customize Tab in Android

Tags: android-emulator

I want to customize tab through height only. When I do through, my text gets down. How to make it on top or middle after reducing the height? I tried `android:gravity="top"` and middle, but its not working. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mitt u can try this http://devtcg.blogspot.com/2008/03/advanced-tab-activity-demo.html. I hope it will work for u